# IBM Watson Studio Desktop Install

Tags: installation, ibm-watson

I’m trying to install IBM Watson Studio Desktop and running installation as administrator. Yet, when I launch the program, it says that I need to set up the program as an Administator. What’s going on?

I’ve tried uninstalling and reinstalling the program several times and keep receiving the same error message when I launch the program.

I’m on a Dell Windows laptop.

Any ideas?